# OpenCV Callback Lag

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm running OpenCV 3 on Python 3.4 on a 2015 15" MacBook Pro. Below is a minimal example that illustrates my problem:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    print("Callback!")

cv.namedWindow("Display")
cv.setMouseCallback("Display", mouse_callback)

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imshow("Display", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
```

When I click on the screen, the text "Callback!" takes about 3 seconds to appear on the terminal screen. I'm not sure why I'm seeing this much lag--my laptop shouldn't be so bad that I can't even run this simple script.

Additionally, the problem persists when I reduce the webcam resolution, or even when I replace the webcam altogether with a still image. I rewrote a similar program in C++, and the C++ OpenCV libraries also suffer from this lag.

Any tips on how I can reduce or eliminate the lag?

Comment: I've run the same on my MBP 15" Early 2011 on Opencv installed from macports. The callback runs fine. The resolution is not the issue. You may want to recompile Opencv if you are compiling from command line. (I personally don't see the requirement for source compiliation if I'm just prototyping; Suggest you try installing the opencv port from Macports or Homebrew whatever suits your poison.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        print("Callback!")

cv.namedWindow("Display")
cv.setMouseCallback("Display", mouse_callback)

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imshow("Display", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
```

Although its mostly a problem with something else. Maybe your webcam resolution is too high.

So try this also:

```
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
```

Put the above code above the while loop and check.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't fix my issue--the problem persists even if I replace the webcam altogether with just a still black image.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is using window.Resize(width, height)